# Assuming you know everything about a hardware platform, can you reverse the BLOB that is required for its operation?

Tags: hardware, binary

I do not understand, if you know everything there is to be known about your hardware, can't you work your way up and find out what the binary does **exactly**?

Answer (score 2):

One problem here is that it might be hard to know all facts about the hardware - a great example are the current Meltdown and Spectre security problems, which rely on side-channel effects not (precisely) documented by the processor vendors.

So in general, in cases like these you would have a hard time figuring out what some piece of binary code trying to exploit these properties really does.

However, since you are asking about a BLOB driving a certain piece of hardware, having descriptions of register, timing, interrupt, DMA (etc.)  behavior and, if possible, schematics or HDL descriptions of the hardware components, would at least go a long way in finding out what the binary does exactly.